# Center an equation in a specific point

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align, center

I would like to know how I can center this equation in the first equal sign (commented with a letter **c** in the picture). Thanks in advance!

Here is my code so far:

```
\begin{align}
J_i &= \frac{J_i '}{\prod\limits_i^{n-1} N_i} \qquad i = \{ 2, \, 3, \dots , \, n-1 \}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could stick everything to the left of the `=` symbol into a `\mathllap` wrapper, and everything to the right of the `=` symbol into a `\mathrlap` wrapper. `\mathllap` and `\mathrlap` (and `\mathclap` too) are macros provided by the `mathtools` package, a superset of the `amsmath` package.

The framelines in the following screenshot denote the left-hand and right-hand edges of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for \mathllap and \mathrlap macros
\usepackage{showframe}  % draw framelines around text block
 
\begin{document}

% original form of equation
\begin{equation}
J_i 
= 
\frac{J_i'}{\prod\limits_i^{n-1} N_i} \qquad i=\{2,3,\dots,n-1\}
\end{equation}

% with \mathllap and \mathrlap
\begin{equation}
\mathllap{J_i}
= 
\mathrlap{\frac{J_i'}{\prod\limits_i^{n-1} N_i} \qquad i=\{2,3,\dots, n-1\}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Should I keep both amsmath and mathtools in the preamble or are they incompatible in the same document?

Comment: @el_maxx - `mathtools` is a superset of `amsmath`, and loads `amsmath` automatically. If you load `mathtools`, there's no need to load `amsmath` separately.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!